# How to enable session in Symfony2?

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, session

How can I enable session in Symfony2? I would like to use Facebook Login, but I get error message: **Session not active, could not store state. (500 Internal Server Error - FacebookSDKException)**.

My code:

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(APP_ID, APP_SECRET);

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(REDIRECT_URL, $appId = NULL, $appSecret = NULL);
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login with Facebook</a> | ';

try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    echo "{ FacebookRequestException }";
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo "{ Exception: }";
}

echo ( isset( $session ) ) ? "{ OK! }" : "{ NOPE }";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `app/config/config.yml`, under `framework` section, you must have a `session` item :

```
framework:
    # ...
    session: ~
```

Have a look to the official documentation to learn how to configure session storage : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#session

Comment: Yes, I know this documentation, but I don't know what I should set. I have never seen any example code. Can I ask for a little hint?

Comment: Just try the default config (in my answer), it will activate session based on your PHP ini file and it's enough to continue.

Comment: Oh, so I had this section set all the time, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: i have same problem. i had printed my session object that i get in controller with $this->get('session'), but it still write that there's no session)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like i found solution, i wrote this in my controller before your code:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $session = $this->get('session');
    $session->start();
    $url = $this->get('fb_provider')->getLoginUrl(); //my service, here execute your code
```

but this strongly confused me

Answer (score 0):

If you want create facebook provider, use this bundle:

https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle

It provide simple access to Facebook and 36 other providers(Google,Twitter).

Instalation of this bundle is very quickly.

You should also be interested in this bundle:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle